# Can you select into a table from one instance to another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

If I have 2 instances, one on a server and another on my local machine. Both have the same database on them (this is for development), but one table changes on 1 instance and I want it to change on the other instance as well without rerunning the query etc. on the other instance, is it possible to `COPY` the table or `INSERT INTO` or `SELECT INTO` a table from the one instance to the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can define a linked server for that use case. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx).

Another approach would be to set up a SSIS package, or use the Data Comparison feature in Visual Studio Data Tools.